# I have two Choi matrix I suspect be equivalent. Can I manipulate them?

Tags: qiskit, density-matrix, matrix-representation, quantum-process-tomography

I am performing a process tomography over a protocol I suspect to be equivalent to the $CS$ gate.

To compare basic operators I usually compute the Choi matrix of the target gate -- which in this case should be $|CS\rangle\rangle\langle\langle CS|$ -- and check if it is (almost) equivalent to the experimental Choi matrix.

Now, when I try to get the experimental matrix of the circuit I wrote, this has some differences with $|CS\rangle\rangle\langle\langle CS|$.

Is it possible that they are still equivalent, what kind of transformation I am allowed to do to the Choi matrix without changing the channel it is representing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a one-to-one relation between Choi states$^1$ and quantum channels ([Choi-Jamiołkowski isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%E2%80%93Jamio%C5%82kowski_isomorphism)). So, you cannot transform the Choi matrix without changing the channel it represents. If the two Choi matrices are different, then they are different quantum channels.

---

<sup>1: Choi states are just normalized Choi matrices. If your map is a valid quantum map, then normalized Choi matrix, i.e. Choi state is a valid quantum state, i.e., the matrix is positive-semidefinite & has unit trace.</sup>

Comment: What about global phases? Is a Choi matrix global-phase independent?